# Не работает поиск по тэгам с одновременным выбором таба newest

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, поиск

Я хочу найти самые новые сообщения по тэгу java, исключая тэг android, на которые нет ответов.

Из этого логично получается [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+-android?tab=newest) вида:
`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+-android?tab=newest`

Интерфейс SO (блок справа) показывает, что поиск производится по верному набору тэгов, но поисковая выдача идет по другим тэгам (похоже, вообще всем тэгам). Если из запроса убрать newest, поисковая выдача становится правильной.

Вопросы:

- можно ли как-нибудь достичь того, что я хочу?
- является ли багом то, что интерфейс SO показывает поиск по тэгам, по
  которым на самом деле поиска не производится? Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+and+-android?tab=newest
```

вроде работает. Только уведомления о новых вопросах не приходят.

Answer (score 3):

> можно ли как-нибудь достичь того, что я хочу?

Вот несколько обходных путей:

1. Посмотреть на [неотвеченные по своим избранным меткам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags). (Для этого нужно их настроить).
2. Искать [`is:q isanswered:no` + желаемые метки, отсортировать по времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[java]%20-[android]%20isanswered%3Ano%20is%3Aq). В результатах поиска будут вопросы с ответами, которые приняты, но имеют нулевой рейтинг.
3. Сначала поискать по меткам, а потом перейти на [вкладку «без ответа»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50). Тут сортировку по времени уже не включить. И здесь НЕ будет вопросов с ответами, которые приняты, но имеют нулевой рейтинг.

Кстати, если система считает вопрос «отвеченным» — необязательно это полностью верный или полный ответ. Наверняка на некоторые «отвеченные» вопросы вы сможете дать ответ лучше, чем уже имеющиеся.

---

> является ли багом...?

На сайте нет ссылки, которая имела бы такой синтаксис, как ваша, написанная вручную. Похоже, сайт просто не умеет это правильно обрабатывать.

А меня, в свою очередь, смутило наличие [вкладки «без ответов»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) на странице «Без ответа». Что, эти ответы ещё более неотвеченные, чем просто неотвеченные?

---

Вообще, на англоязычном SO уже давно обкатывается другая система, заменившая табы и категории. Поэтому исправлять баги в старой наверняка не будут. Нам проще будет дождаться новой системы, с новыми багами. :)